# Does Adobe Flex have the ability to compile into HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flexjs

I'm fairly sure I know what the answer will be here, but since I recently stumbled across *Apache* FlexJS: https://blogs.apache.org/flex/entry/apache_flexjs_0_6_0 I thought I would double-check.

Is there a way to compile Adobe Flex applications into HTML/JavaScript, using the Adobe Flex SDK? I have done some digging and this new development on the Apache Flex project seems to be the only path forward in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory yes, as described on the schema of https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexJS : you get the same source code and can compile it into HTML/JS or SWC.

However, in practice you will get issues because the component library is currently very limited in HTML/JS.

Comment: Right - so not so much the Adobe SDKs, but switch to the FlexJS Apache compilers and use them on the same source code (with a bit of crossing fingers thrown in). Cheers!